# To produce an audit trail of information, to keep track on the changes, create a trigger at database level

Tags: mysql, triggers, audit-trail

Suppose there are n number of tables in the database. Whatever insert,update,delete happen across any table in the database have to be captured in a table called "Audit_Trial", where we have the below columns in the audit trial tables.

```
 Server_Name, AT_date, AT_time, Table_name, Column_name, Action, Old_value, New_Value.
```

Which server on which table on which column on which date and time data has been changed that has to be captured. Also, the "Action" column tracks whether an action is an insert, update or delete and we have to capture the old value and new value as well.

So what is the best way to do this? Can we create a database level trigger which can fire trigger in case of any insert, update or delete? Please explain with an example how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/auditlog.html](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/auditlog.html)

Although it doesn't use triggers, it does provide audit trail on a per-column and table basis.